# AlertDialog not shown after clicking Notification

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, notifications, android-alertdialog

I am triying to do the following:

My app has an AsyncTask that eventually creates an AlertDialog to request the user to isert a code. This can happend when the app is in the foreground, so I launch a notification to inform the user and my idea is that once he clicks the notification, the main activity with the AlertDialog is shown.

Nevertheless what is happening is that once the user clicks on the notification, just the activity where the AlertDialog is supposed to be is shown and I get a WindowLeaked exception probably caused by the Dialog.

There is the code that I am using to launch the notification (from the method onProgressUpdate of the AsyncTask):

```
public void launch_notification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.opening_request_notification_title))
                    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.opening_request_notification_text));
    /* The intent must be created with an specific content and then frozen to be used
    later using a pending intent.
     */
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Any idea will be welcome.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Better to create a separate Activity(example DialogActivity) and in your manifest set  for DialogActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your notification creation seems fine and you invoke the method from onProgressUpdate which is also fine.
So there must be something wrong with your activity and the way it handles the dialog.

If you could provide your Main class we could know for sure, but what I guess is happening that in your AsyncTask you show some sort of dialog, perhaps a progress dialog.
If that is the case then when you get the notification (on progress update) and you click it you start Main activity again, so you end up creating another instance of main activity, and hence the leaking window.
Try adding the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).
As the API states:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

Hope that this will help you out.